# Turn one column into multiple

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to turn a single column of data,

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

into:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

I figured it would be something to do with pivots but I'm still unsure how to accomplish this.

Comment: This is not what SQL is made for. Your result shows two rows representing two relations: The values 1, 2, and 3 belong together, and the values 4, 5, and 6 belong together. But there is nothing in your table to suggest this relation. If you merely want to use this presentation style in your app to list the values and save space on the screen, then it is the app's task to care about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using a pivot query with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 1 THEN id END) AS col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 2 THEN id END) AS col2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 0 THEN id END) AS col3
FROM cte
GROUP BY (rn - 1) / 3;
```

### Demo

Comment: Yeah that works perfectly, thank you. Can you explain the "group by" rationale?

Comment: Taking the first 3 row number values of 1, 2, 3, minus 1, if we divide by 3 we get a quotient of 0 and the decimal component gets cut off.  So the first "group" of 3 `id` values is 0.  Next, 4, 5, 6 gives a quotient of 1, no decimal component, so the second group is 1, and so on...

Comment: @Jack: `select rn, (rn - 1) / 3, rn % 3 from cte` to see the expressions' results. Then think about what happens when you aply `GROUP BY`.